# CLion CMake targets build view

Tags: cmake, clion

Recently I changed from Eclipse/Makefiles to CLion and to the usage of CMake.

Some of the projects that I work on are still based on `Makefile`s, but I have the `CMakeLists.txt` for symbols/include search.

I added custom targets to run the commands from the `Makefile`s, the same way I would add "Build targets" in Eclipse:

```
add_custom_target(
        build
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my/dir
        COMMAND make my_make_target)
```

Now, if I want to build/clean/test the project I need to choose the specific target and then click on "Build". Is there any faster way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html), you can add the `ALL` option to include the target to the default build target (whichever that is)

```
add_custom_target(
        build
        ALL
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my/dir
        COMMAND make my_make_target)
```